# Alter text in Button after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm hitting some trouble in trying to change the text in a button after a user clicks on the wishlist link. The Ajax call is working successfully right now and the data is updated correctly in the DB, currently the function displays a notification pop up in the browser when a user clicks on wishlist, but I would like to change the "wishlist" part of the button to "Added to wishlist" after a successful submission.

EDIT:

I have added `$("#btn span").text("Added to wishlist");`

But it's still not working.

```
function wish($p_id){
    var w_id = $p_id;
    var email = $(".wish").data("user");

    if(email != 0){
        $.ajax({
            url:"function.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{w_id:w_id,email:email},
            success: function($wish){
                if($wish > 0){
                    notif({
                        msg:"Product Already Added to wishlist!!!",
                        type:"warning",
                        width:330,
                        height:40,
                        timeout:1000,
                    })
                }else{
                   $("#btn span").text("Added to wishlist"); 
                    notif({
                        msg:"Added to wishlist",
                        type:"success",
                        width:330,
                        height:40,
                        timeout:1000,
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and the HTML part

```
<a href='$add_wish' id="btn"class='btn btn-default add-to-cart wish' data-user='$s_email' onclick='wish($id)'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i> Wishlist
</a>
```

Comment: Having trouble how, exactly? I don't see any attempt at modifying the button at all. Where precisely are you stuck? Also, is there more than one of these buttons on your page at any one time? (and if so, presumably you only want to update the one which was actually clicked?) That might make a slight difference to any solution.

Comment: P.S. This has nothing to do with PHP, and much more to do with HTML, so I re-tagged your question.

Comment: And when you look at the Page Source in the browser, what does the Anchor tag look like then?

Comment: I have added I have added $("#btn span").text("Added to wishlist");

Comment: Did you start the debugger in the browser, and set a breakpoint on the first line of the function to a) see if its getting run and b) check that a parameter is passed and the param looks sensible?

Comment: `$("#btn span")`...? Why? Your button doesn't have `id="btn"` and also doesn't contain a `span` element inside it. Was that complete guesswork? Do you understand how selectors work?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ok (after your edit) now you have the right `id` but there's clearly still no `<span>` inside the button, is there?

Comment: yes, I now removed <span> and it its now working.

Comment: @ADyson You now appear to be an interactive cloud debugger, cool :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly all my dreams have come true. Maybe my comment data can be scraped to make an AI which suggests fixes or points out coding problems in natural language. Then I can go back whatever it is I'm supposed to do instead of this. :-)

Comment: I rolled back your last edits. Don't alter the question to contain the solution instead of the original code - it makes the comments and answers nonsensical and obscures the original problem. This is really unhelpful for future readers (who remember, are also the audience for this content). The answers already exist below, you don't need to repeat them in the question :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in this code:

```
$("#btn span").text("Added to wishlist");
```

your selector is missing the target. It tries to find an element with the ID of "btn", which is fine, but then it tries to look for a `<span>` element inside that, which doesn't exist.

It's trivial to resolve of course by wrapping the text in the expected `<span>`:

```js
$("#btn span").text("Added to wishlist");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='$add_wish' id="btn"class='btn btn-default add-to-cart wish' data-user='$s_email' onclick='wish($id)'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i>
    <span>Wishlist</span>
</a>
```

---

N.B. Note that writing simply

```
$("#btn").text("Added to wishlist")
```

is undesirable because it will erase the `<i>` containing the icon.

Demo (for comparison with above):

```js
$("#btn").text("Added to wishlist");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='$add_wish' id="btn"class='btn btn-default add-to-cart wish' data-user='$s_email' onclick='wish($id)'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i>
    Wishlist
</a>
```

Relevant documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Identify your button by adding an id and put your text inside a span

```
<a href='$add_wish' id='my_button' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart wish' data-user='$s_email' onclick='wish($id)'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i> <span>Wishlist</span>
</a>
```

You have to change the `innerText` of the span, just add the following code after the product is added :

```
document.querySelector('#my_button span').innerText = 'Added to wishlist';
```

Comment: If @ADyson 's answer is okay for you, please let us know by accepting it. However, you should check your selector, I test my answers before publishing them

Comment: Actually upon further testing your answer is also working after changing '#my_button span' to '#my_button' since I incorrectly used the <span> option in button.